# Trouble setting up SSH "Connection Timed out" on Headless RPI 4

Tags: ssh, connection

I've decided to enter into the world of HomeLabs with the acquisition of an RPI 4. I went throught the procedure of setting up the RPI and everything worked correctly.
I've used both a(n) dynamic/automatic IP, pulled IP using IPanalyzer, threw the SSH file into boot through CMD and launched up MobaXTerm. The first time the SSH client worked perfectly. Now, after I've travelled with the RPI (May have been damaged in the process) and swapped out the SD for a class 3 micro-sd because I damaged the original class 10 (it's no longer detected properly by the pc). I've installed the Raspbian using the imager on the new SD.
When I try to connect I simply get "Connection Timed Out" after a few moments. After a reboot, I can ping the RPI and it'll receive a packet and state "Destination Host Unavailable".
Is this a sign that the RPI is a dud? the red LED still lights up. If anyone can tell me how I can find out more about the hardware condition using a headless connection/headless RPI or if anyone figures that I ought to try something please don't hesitate to ask/notify me.

Thanks in advance,
Merle

Edit: I forgot to mention I'm using an ethernet cable between the PC and RPI4.

Comment: It sounds as though your pi is not on the network, 'Destination Host Unavailable" means it's not there.  This could be for any  number of reasons, it will need to obtain its address from a DHCP server and you haven't mentioned using one.   Why not connect a keyboard and monitor to the pi and see if it boots, you can also check out the network status `ifconfig -a` will show the interfaces and IP addresses assigned to them.

Comment: I'll try to pick up a USB-keyboard tomorrow, if not on Monday. You said the Pi isn't on the network. I've connected it physically to the PC with an Ethernet cable and it shows up as a Local network on the PC.

Comment: What do you mean by "it shows up on as a local network"?   Do you have a DHCP server on the PC?  Normally, you would connect them to a switch or router which would hand out IP addresses and configure the network for you.  If not then I guess you could use IPV6 and connect via those local addresses.

Comment: I've connectly it directly to my laptop as I've stated using an ethernet cable. I haven't set up a DHCP server knowingly, I'm using IPv4 and the lappy is assigning the IP to the RPI. What I meant to say is that the laptop recognizes the RPI and it's IP address when I use IP scanner.

Comment: You are probably pinging and attempting to connect to the wrong IP. Try this: https://www.circuitbasics.com/how-to-connect-to-a-raspberry-pi-directly-with-an-ethernet-cable/

Comment: Try writing in paragraphs and people will be more inclined to try and work out what you are asking.

Comment: I've booted up my RPI 4 with peripherals. It boots up normally and appears to be functioning properly. I've enabled SSH in the hope that I'll be using this unit headless soon. When checking the device IP on the RPI using 'ifconfig eth0', I'm told the IP address is 169.254 yada yada. When I connect it to the WiFi and use IP scanner the RPI has a different IP in the network. Is it normal for a host to have two IPs like this?